# Select row in group by min of another column

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

Hey can you help me with my simple sql query ?

**Tables**

Hotel

```
id | name | country | rating
1    Bali   bg        4.5
2    Beach  uk        4.0
3    Blue   sk        3.7
```

Tour

```
id | id_hotel | price  
1    2          250
2    2          270
3    1          250
4    1          300
5    3          250
```

And I want something like this

```
SELECT t.* FROM tour t LEFT JOIN hotel h ON  t.id_hotel = h.id
WHERE h.country = uk GROUP BY h.id ORDER BY t.price
```

So I wanna get only one row for each one hotel with min tour price.
And best with using Doctrine 2 queryBuilder.

Thanks for help.

Comment: There's really no point outer joining tables from which you select no columns, and GROUP BY need never appear in a query absent of any aggregation. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Hey prbably I have solution

```
SELECT MIN(tour.id), hotel.* FROM `tour` INNER JOIN (
SELECT MIN(t.final_price) as final_price, t.id_hotel FROM tour t GROUP 
BY t.id_hotel) ht 
ON tour.id_hotel = ht.id_hotel AND tour.final_price = 
ht.final_price 
LEFT JOIN hotel ON hotel.id = tour.id_hotel GROUP BY tour.id_hotel
```

Comment: `hotel.id` is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Does this query run?

Comment: Yes, this query working for me, but there is a small problem, I cant use where conditions for table tour, because the inner join find the smallest price for every each hotel. But if I want searching only tours where for example id_tourType = 1 I must put this condition to subquery and create some CONCAT key for JOIN ON. Its very difficult.

Comment: Exist something like FIRST() ? For example SELECT FIRST(tour.id) FROM tours LEFT JOIN hotel ........ WHERE tour.column = value AND .... AND hotel.country = uk etc.. ORDER tour.price ASC GROUP tour.id_hotel. This would be amazing !

Answer (score -1):

Use group by with order by to accomplish your result, try below query

```
select hotel.name,Tour.id,Tour.price,Hotel.rating from Hotel inner join Tour on Tour.id_hotel = Hotel.id group where hotel.country = 'uk' group by Tour.id_hotel order by Tour.price asc
```

Let me know if it helps

[Edit] This query should work with you

Comment: This is the problem, with nonagregatted column tour.id because if I want group by hotel, is there many row of tours with differents ID and I want get row where is the MIN(price)

Comment: Group by, order by price asc does the same as MIN(price)... try my answer should work well with you

Comment: Ok sorry, Iam trying this

SELECT tour.id FROM hotel INNER JOIN tour ON tour.id_hotel = hotel.id GROUP BY tour.id_hotel ORDER BY tour.price ASC

And I got this
SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'tour.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: So I want only one tour_id but with the smallest price